# HttpNotFound with custom 404

Tags: pipelines, sitecore-mvc

In one of our MVC controllers we have:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return HttpNotFound();
}
```

This `HttpNotFound` will set the StatusCode to `404`. We would like to 'catch' this `404` status code and show a custom `404` page by changing the `Context.Item` into this custom 404 item.

In what kind of pipeline/processor should we hack in to change the `context.item` so that we get our nice custom `404` page rendered?

Kr,

Comment: Did you check before asking?  we have dozens of different articles already on 404 handling. https://www.google.com/search?q=sitecore+stack+exchance+custom+404+site:sitecore.stackexchange.com

Comment: Already spent a couple of hours on different ways to get this working ... so yes, did check before asking

Comment: Are there any additional suggestions ... ? I'm not able to get this working. I'm able to switch the context.item but the previous item is still rendered. The context.item switch is not picked up appearantly ... probably because i'm too late in the pipelines.